Converting vertices of lines features to points with elevation and steepness with QGIS Virtual Layer
I am looking for a very similar solution to the one for polygons but for a simple line layer and with some additional data included on the points:

elevation from a DTM (available as a layer in the project)
steepness calculation (based on rise/run)


When setting up a dependence in the virtual layer, the following allows for rendering points at each vertex of the line(s) and the steepness calculations are updated on each save of the line layer.
/*
Tested on QGIS 3.36 
with a multilinestring layer (from a PostGIS DB)
and a 1meter per pixel smoothed DTM (derived from drone data)
*/

WITH points as (

    SELECT 
        row_number() over(partition by name) as fid,
        st_x(geometry) as x,
        st_y(geometry) as y,
        AsText(geometry) as geoText, 
        raster_value('01.DTM.2024.01mpp',1, geometry) AS elev, 
        * 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            word,
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| word ||')') as geometry,
            name 
        FROM (
            WITH split(word, name, str) AS (
            SELECT 
                '',
                name, 
                regexp_replace(AsText(geometry),'[^\d\.\s,]+|(?<=,)\s+','')||',' 
            FROM polygons
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                substr(str, 0, instr(str, ',')), 
                name,
                substr(str, instr(str, ',')+1)
            FROM split
            WHERE str!='') SELECT distinct name,rtrim(word,',') as word FROM split WHERE word!=''
        )
    )
) SELECT 
    a.fid,
    a.geometry,
    a.elev,
    CASE 
        WHEN st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) > 0 THEN 
            ((a."elev" - b."elev") / st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry)) * 100
        ELSE 
            0
    END AS steepness
FROM 
    points AS a
JOIN 
    points AS b ON a.fid = b.fid + 1

For example when designing a road along a property border, this can show which spots are higher than a certain threshold (eg 15%).
Here is a shot with one spot too steep:

Here is an adjustment of the path to avoid any spots over 15%:

Note: It seems that i need to edit the virtual layer and re-add it after closing and opening qgis.
